# How to set random TextView's position inside linear layout?

Tags: java, android

I have a linearlayout on xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And I add dynamic 100 textviews inside it by code below:

```
        llayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            int randomInt = new Random().nextInt(100) +1 ;
            tv.setText(""+randomInt);       
            llayout.addView(tv);
        }
```

The result is 100 textviews added and display vertically. This is not as my expect. I want these textviews display with random position inside the layout look like the image below:
[image]

How to do it? Thank you!

Comment: have you find the solution that how we can set these numbers to not overlap on with each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinearLayout` is for layouting its children linearly (as the name suggests).

As there is no `RandomLayout`, you can use a `RelativeLayout` with random left and top layout margins, or an `AbsoluteLayout` and set random x and y.

**Edit: Avoid overlapping texts**

Random positions can of course lead to overlapping and it would be up to you to adjust the positions or ignore positions too similar to previous ones. Or you might actually compare the bounding boxes (left, top, width, height) of the view you're about to add to all other views in the container and if there is any overlapping, find another place for it.

Comment: I use AbsoluteLayout and textviews can display random now. How to avoid textviews overlap together ?

Comment: how we can set these numbers to not overlap on with each other

Answer (score 2):

You can use tv.setX(position) and tv.setY(position) for show view on specific position

Comment: Thanks for your answer, How to avoid these textview overlap together ?

Comment: @Hnib Have you found the solution to put textview in relative layout at rendom position and How to avoid these textview overlap each other?